# Get data from a Collection of maps with 2 int as parameters

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, iterator

I have a variable like:

```
Collection<Map<String, String>> allFieldValues;
```

In this variable I have all the data of a sqlite Table, each map of the collection represents a row of the table.

Now I have to take the data of a specific cell, my parameters are 2 ints (row number, column number), so I am trying something like this:

```
Iterator<Map<String, String>> iter = allFieldValues.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i == givenRowAsParameter; i++)
{
    iter.next();
}
```

And thats it, the iter that I get out of the loop its supossed to be the row that I want, but I can't take another Iterator from that Iterator to search for the column, neither I can't get a specific object of the iterator with just an int as a parameter. So Im stuck :(

Any suggestions? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your methodology for defining row index, you can use:

```
Iterator<Map<String, String>> iter = allFieldValues.iterator();
Map<String, String> row;
for (int i = 0; i <= rowIndex; i++) {
    row = iter.next();
}

String col;
Iterator<String> iter2 = row.values().iterator();
for (int i = 0; i <= colIndex; i++) {
    col = iter2.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man,perfect answer, didn't know about the .values() method. still don't know why I have to use it to get the Iterator, but it works!! Thanks!

Comment: @jose The map contains keys (probably column names in your case) available through the `keySet()` method, and also the `values()` collection which you use to iterate over the field values. When you have a chance, please mark the answer as accepted.